# Distance between stars Epsilon Eridani and Tau Ceti?

Tags: star, distances

I am working on a story. It would be helpful if someone could provide the distance in light years between star Epsilon Eridani and star Tau Ceti.

[image: star graph]

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance+between+tau+ceti+and+epsilon+eridani

Comment: I suspect you're writing a Star Trek story ;)

Comment: Nope  @barrycarter

Comment: This page had the 3d position of those, and shows how to do the computation so you can verify the correctness yourself. https://celestialprogramming.com/snippets/starxyz.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered by [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance%20between%20tau%20ceti%20and%20epsilon%20eridani), (as linked by chirlu) The distance between Tau Ceti and Epsilon Eridani is 5.45 light years.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that sort of thing of WolframAlpha - thanks.

Comment: @StephenG Wolfram alpha is convenient fo one-line answers but it's sometimes just plain wrong. It can not be trusted as an authoritative source because it's just a  mindless robot when it comes to text-based queries. [Why doesn't Wolfram Alpha show low gravitational acceleration for the Hudson Bay?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16787/6031)

Answer (score 2):

Using the data from http://www.johnstonsarchive.net/astro/nearstar.html I calculated 5.462 ly. The reference list stars to 25.1 ly with x, y, z coordinates and Right ascension, Declination and distance from our sun.